# Where can I see this Darth Vader church?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this, architecture, religion

Recently, I saw a picture that shows a Darth Vader bust:

[image]

It seems to be a church or something similar. For me it looks like a big fake, but my friend swears that this is not photoshopped. Therefore, I would like to know where I can see this Darth Vader bust in reality. Where do I have to travel to? And what is the story behind this unusual bust?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's on the northwest tower of the Washington National Cathedral in Washington, DC.  There's [an informative page about it on the cathedral's website](http://www.nationalcathedral.org/about/darthVader.shtml):

You can see it from ground level, but they advise binoculars.

As for why it's there:

> Washington National Cathedral held a decorative sculpture competition for children... The
>   third-place winner was Christopher Rader, with his drawing of that fearful villain, Darth  Vader.

Comment: Did it survive the 2011 earthquake?

Answer (score 12):

Amazingly it was a kid's competition that got it there.  The Washington National Cathedral in Washington, DC - where Star Wars villain’s sculpted image sits next to a raccoon 200ft up America’s national house of prayer.

A story about it in [The Sun](http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/news/2723539/Darth-Vader-is-made-into-a-cathedral-gargoyle.html).

[The Wikipedia article on the Cathedral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_National_Cathedral) has more information too:

> The Cathedral boasts what is probably the world's only sculpture of
>   Darth Vader on a religious building. During construction of the west
>   towers of the Cathedral, developers decided to hold a competition for
>   children to design decorative sculptures for the Cathedral. The image
>   of the villainous Vader, sculpted by Jay Hall Carpenter and carved by
>   Patrick J. Plunkett, was placed high upon the northwest tower of the
>   Cathedral, fulfilling the role of a traditional grotesque.

Answer (score 8):

Not contradicting the references to the Darth Vader sculpture on The Washington National Cathedral in Washington I would like to direct you to two buildings in Spain.

[Sagrada familia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagrada_Fam%C3%ADlia) is a famous cathedral in Barcelona, Spain. The architect behind it is the late [Antoni Gaudi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoni_Gaud%C3%AD). He is also the architect behind the building [Casa Mila](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casa_Mil%C3%A0). Both buildings are equipped with sculptures/design elements which reminds the spectator about Star Wars storm troopers.

The blog [Sistersbailey](http://sistersbailey.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/sacred-family/) mentions that George Lucas was inspired by Gaudis Roman guards for his storm troopers. Many other webpages says things like "[..] it is said that George Lucas was inspired[..]", but I have not found a proper reference to this. In an age where Apple can copyright a telephone with rounded edges my guess is that Lucas wouldn't stand a chance in court.

[image: Casa Mila ventilation ventilation towers (Source Wikipedia)]

Casa Mila Ventilation ventilation towers ([Source Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Casa_Mil%C3%A0_01.jpg))

You might also find [Nelson Mandela Metropolitan University](http://www.nmmu.ac.za/) interesting. I went there around 10 years ago and the architecture took me on a Star Wars ride. I would not have been a tad surprised if a storm-trooper suddenly came walking across campus.

Comment: Is it wrong that this image reminds me of Mount Rushmore?

Comment: You can tell that they're all female except the one on the left. He's the only one with an [Adam's apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam's_apple).